# Django adding objects to other objects in a many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-admin

I am building a Django backend and I have two models like this

```
class A(models.Model):
     name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)

class B(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
    a = models.manytomanyfield(A)
```

I have created several objects of both and when I go to create a new B object all of the class A objects created before are already listed in the relationship. How can I fix this so that There are no A objects in the relationship for a new B object until I add one?

Comment: No they aren't. They are just presented as options for you to select.

Comment: You're right, Thanks man.